# Laravel - How to get a foreign key and pass it to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a survey and in order to create a question I need to get the `survey_id` from the survey table and place in it a create a question view in a hidden field in a form and pass it to the question controller.

Comment: Can you `dd($request->all())` before your `create()` method to see if data is being passed through?

Comment: Yeah doesn't look like any data is being pass through I've added the survey controller store method is which i'm guessing where i have to pass the id through

Comment: Should be passed to the `QuestionController` if I am correct

Comment: That's where i'm stuck i'm unsure on how to do this

Comment: Can you update your question with all your form markup.

Answer (score 0):

Since you passe survey_id all you need to the do is use the right model (Question) in the store method, everything else same correct.

```php
 /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $input = $request->all();
      Question::create($input); //<==== You need to use Question insteed of Survey
      return redirect('survey');
    }
```

Comment: It looks like i'm not passing the survey_id which is where i'm stuck at but this will help me when i solve that issue thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code,i hope this is help you:

```
$input = $request->all();
$survey = new Survey ();
$survey ->fill($input)->save();
if (isset($input['survey_id']) && !empty($input['survey_id'])) {
            $survey_id= $input['survey_id'];

            foreach ($survey_id as $index => $value) {
                Question::create([
                    'survey_id' => $survey ->id,
                    'title' => $value
                ]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rachid's comments is right, but its not the reason of the error...

The problem is the resource's `route -> controler@action` mapping doesn't include any param for the `/create` route as we can see bellow...

[image: From Laravel's resource controller documentation...]

... and your `QuestionController::create` function needs the param `$id`.

```
//...
class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create($id) // <---- Right here...
//...
```

So, to bind your foreign key to this resource i'll need to do something like this...

```
Route::resource('survey.question', 'QuestionController');
```

This way you'll have your routes mapped sothing like this...

```
GET /survey/{survey}/question           survey.question.index
GET /survey/{survey}/question/create    survey.question.create
```

Then change your template, from:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'QuestionController@store', 'id' => 'Question')) !!}
```

To:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'QuestionController@store', 'id' => 'Question'), ['survey' => Request::route('survey')]) !!}
```

Then you can use your `QuestionController::create` function like this...

```
public function create(Survey $survey)
{
    return view('question.create')->with('survey', $survey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use parameters in resourceful routes like this:

```php
Route::resource('survey/{survey}/question', 'QuestionController');
```

Then in your controller you can use:

```php
class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create($id)
    {
        // $id will be the {survey} id from the route parameter.
    }

    // ...
}
```

You could as well use route model binding to avoid the manual Survey retrival in the controller:

```php
use App\Survey;

class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(Survey $survey)
    {
        return view('question.create', compact('survey'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Remember to update the form action as well to include the pameter

**Be Careful!**
If you register the parameter in the resource like I have shown, methods as show, edit, update and destroy (that accepts the id of the resource to act on in the url) will receive two route parameters, one will be the **survey id**, the second one would be the **question id** (your resource).
Keep that in mind!